# Gramar question -"She is going to marry him in spite of that he is very poor"

Tags: grammar

> "She is going to marry him in spite of that he is very poor"

I think there is a problem in that sentence but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the use of *in spite of that*, a conjunctive adverb, being used as a regular adverb.

Either of these would be fine:

> 1. She is going to marry him; in spite of that, he is very poor.
>   2. She is going to marry him in spite of *the fact* that he is very poor.